# Python Panda cannot get a number field from a spreadsheet to load to INT field

Tags: python, pandas, upload, integer, spreadsheet

I am trying to load a spreadsheet to a table and the 4 field is a INT and the 8 field is a Date.

My code looks like this:

```
    df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
    n_rows = df.shape[0]
    for i in range(0, n_rows):
        pdpd_id = df.loc[i][0]
        benefit_line = df.loc[i][1]
        benefit_desc = df.loc[i][2]
        benefit_value = df.loc[i][3].astype(str).astype(int)
        benefit_type = df.loc[i][4]
        detail = df.loc[i][5]
        network_ind = df.loc[i][6]
        prod_type = df.loc[i][7]
        load_date = df.loc[i][8].astype(str).astype(datetime)
        self.ODBCManager.insert_product_benefits(pdpd_id, benefit_line, benefit_desc, benefit_value, benefit_type, detail, network_ind, prod_type, load_date)
```

I get this error - **pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('Invalid parameter type.  param-index=3 param-type=numpy.int32', 'HY105')**

I am guessing that since **param-index=3** is in the error message it is failing on the INT field.

I have tried converting the fields but I must be doing something wrong in my code

Comment: I would not convert the columns by a for loop. The value 'HY105' does not look an integer.

Comment: Did any of these answers address your question. If they do you can check and/or upvote them. If they don't provide a comment and state what is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I would do. The pandas read_ is able to determine the types, but sometimes it works better if you declare the types.

```
df = pd.read_excel(self.filename, dtype = {'benefit_value':'int'}, parse_dates=['load_date'])
print(df.dtypes)
```

Check the print results to see that it worked right. Should it not have worked then you can do it separately like below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel(self.filename)
df['benefit_value'] = df.astype({'benefit_value': np.int64})
df['load_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['load_date']).dt.date
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use .loc[index][column] you get value so just try:

a) if you want string:

```
benefit_value = str(df.loc[i][3])
```

b) if you want integer:

```
benefit_value = int(dr.loc[i][3])
```

c) if you want float:

```
benefit_value = float(dr.loc[i][3])
```

d) if you want datetime:

```
load_date = datetime.strptime(df.loc[i][8], '%m/%d/%y')
```

Last point depends on your date format.

For example, if you have '2022-02-12' you should use this format: '%Y-%m-%d'

See more: https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-datetime-strptime-function/amp/